# How to match the two strings with and without including spaces

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For example: In DB I've the string value like `"cell phones"`. If I get the string value like `"cellphones"` from frontend. How can I compare it with DB string and get the related string values in response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove those spaces from the response you are getting after query find then pass the response to require input field. Then match that string with front-end or input string. If both matches load the required content.
Suppose the collection name is Category. Then the sample query will be like this

```
Category.find().exec((err, categories) => {
         var details=[]
         var matchCategory=[]
         categories.map((category,key)=>{
           var obj ={}
           obj.name = category.name.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "")
           details.push(obj);
         })
       if(details.length > 0){
         var detailsLength=details.length
         details.map((category,key)=>{
             if(category.name=="cellphones"){ // match your input string 
               matchCategory.push(category)
             }
             detailsLength--
         })
         if(detailsLength==0){
               resolve(matchCategory);
         }
       }
     })
```

This may help you to reach out.

Answer (score 10):

You can compare so:

```js
let val1 = 'cell phones';
let val2 = 'cellphones';

console.log(val1.replace(/\s/g, '') === val2.replace(/\s/g, '')) // true
//OR
console.log(val1.split(' ').join('') === val2.split(' ').join('')) // true
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need some aggregation trick then  you can try this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "name": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": { "$split": ["$name", " "] },
        "initialValue": "",
        "in": { "$concat": ["$$value", "$$this"] }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$match": { "name": "cellphones" }}
])
```

You can test it 
[**Here**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WqLmmmpwH4v)

Answer (score 5):

You can first start by stripping out the spaces on both the strings before comparing them, for example:

```js
let a = "cell phone";
let b = "cellphone";
let c = "cell phones"

const stripSpaces = s => s.replace(/\s/g, '');

// compare
console.log(stripSpaces(a) == stripSpaces(b)); // true
console.log(stripSpaces(a) == stripSpaces(c)); // false
```

Answer (score 4):

Answers below this question are good, like using `where` and `Regex`, but might be at their best if you got a small number of docs that you may want to query from.

If you got many docs, I'd suggest you:
  1. Use an extra field like `cellphone` without any space, if the values of the original field are expected to be short.
  2. Try using search engines, like ElasticSearch, or MongoDB's own text search, to find what you need, not only `cell phone` to `cellphone`, but `mobile phone` even `smartphone`.  Actually, when you google something, the suggestions while you're typing are also coming from similar but more complex algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

Given a document like this:

```
{
    "text" : "cell phones"
}
```

You could use the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator like this:

```
db.collection.find({
    $where: function() {
        return this.text.replace(' ', '') == "cellphones"
    }
});
```

I wouldn't necessarily recommend this for big collections (performance might not be great). However, even with big collections you could supposedly achieve some pretty ok performance by adding an extra filter on the `"text"` field to filter out all documents that don't start with the correct first character(s):

```
db.collection.find({
    "text": { $regex: "^" + "cellphones".charAt(0) }, // this will use an index on the "text" field if available
    $where: function() {
        return this.text.replace(' ', '') == "cellphones"
    }
});
```

Or perhaps even this version with yet another filter in the `$where` bit that checks the string lengths for a reduced number of string comparisons:

```
db.collection.find({
    "text": { $regex: "^" + "cellphones".charAt(0) }, // this will use an index on the "text" field if available
    $where: function() {
        return this.text.length >= "cellphones".length // performance shortcut
               && this.text.replace(' ', '') == "cellphones"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first start by stripping out the spaces on both the strings before comparing them. I'm assuming you don't know which one has spaces before hand, so you will run all the values through the `stripSpaces` function, for example:

```js
let a = "cell phone";
let b = "cellphone";
let c = "cell phones"

const stripSpaces = (s) => s.split(' ').join('');

// compare
console.log(stripSpaces(a) == stripSpaces(b)); // true
console.log(stripSpaces(a) == stripSpaces(c)); // false
```

Comment: @AlluManikyam - is it possible to share portion of code for better context, you can use http://pastebin.com then we can refine the question.

Answer (score 2):

try replacing empty string from query string first, and then compare to the field as

```
db.test.find(function() { 
    return this.data(function(elm) {
        "cell phones".replace(/ /g,"") == elm.name
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

May be it solves Your problem

```
   Take Device_Names column contains 

               "cell phone"
               "mobile phone"
               "cellphone"
               "laptop"
```

1.) Normal way:

```
    select Device_Name from devices where Device_Name='cellphone' ;

             result: 
                    "cellphone"

      which is third one
```

2.)By Remove spaces:

```
  SELECT  Device_Name FROM devices WHERE REPLACE(Device_Name, ' ', '')='cellphone'

               result: 
                    "cell phone"
                    "cellphone"

       which includes first and third one
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use of a regex when looking for your value, like :

```
cellphones|cell phones
```

---

```
Collection.find({
  someName: {
     $regex: new RegExp('cellphones|cell phones', ''),
  },
});
```